# In R, sorting character vectors: how to specify sorting orders

Tags: r, sorting, character

I have a little problem with sorting in R in presence of character vectors.
I would like to sort

```
x<- c("q1","q4","q40","q10")
```

w.r.t. the numbers 1<4<10<40 appearing in its components. I n other words, I would like to arrive at the following output

```
[1] "q1"  "q4" "q10"  "q40"
```

Applying `sort` to `x` I arrive at

```
 sort(x)
 [1] "q1"  "q10" "q4"  "q40"
```

instead (this output makes sense to me, but it is not what I would like to obtain).
I thought about removing the characters `""` and `q` in each component, and then apply `sort` to the resulting numeric vector. I would like to try something simpler, though. Any help is much appreciated!

I thank you all.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551914/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-vector-of-alphanumeric-values-using-lexical-ordering-in/15556495#15556495. Don't know what you consider simple, but check `mixedsort` in `gtools` package.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778039/how-to-do-an-alphanumeric-sort-in-r/2778060#2778060

Comment: mixedsort works very well: I thank you, Henrik!